# How can I find the cause of this error? We’ve detected that your app is using an old version of the Google Play developer API

Tags: android, google-play

My Google Play Console welcomes me with this message every time I log in:

We’ve detected that your app is using an old version of the Google Play developer API. From 1 December 2019, versions 1 and 2 of this API will no longer be available. Update to version 3 before this date.

How do I even find the cause of this problem?
What is this even?

Comment: But I'm not using such services.

Comment: Sorry, I misread google play as google pay.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO! Does the play console mention which app is causing this (assuming you have more than one?), what do you use PS for?

Comment: PS? What is that?

Comment: I have the same warning, I don't use this API

Comment: Please post your build.grade files. Do you have set a correct minSDK Level?
Do you have a very old apk in the internal, alpha or beta channels active?